# Error shown when executing the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Issues are occurring when executing the stored procedure.

Errors like :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Here is my query:

```
Create procedure [dbo].[Mysp]
as
BEGIN
    Declare @Id int
    Declare @MyspRemainingIdFromProduct varchar(max)
    Declare @StoreDeleteQuery varchar(max)
    Declare @i int
    Declare @MyspAddIdFromProduct varchar(max)

    set @MyspRemainingIdFromProduct = 
           (SELECT Mysp_abc_Product.Id 
            FROM Mysp_abc_Product 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Product ON Mysp_abc_Product.ID = Product.ID
            WHERE Product.ID IS NULL)

    set @StoreDeleteQuery = 'DELETE FROM Mysp_abc_Product WHERE Id IN (' + @MyspRemainingIdFromProduct + ')'

    exec(@StoreDeleteQuery)

    set @MyspAddIdFromProduct =   
           (SELECT Product.Id 
            FROM Product 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Mysp_abc_Product ON Mysp_abc_Product.ID = Product.ID
            WHERE Mysp_abc_Product.ID IS NULL)

    WHILE (@i <= @MyspAddIdFromProduct)
    BEGIN
        --Insert data into Mysp_abc_Product where condition is p.Deleted = 'False' or p.Published = 'True' or  VisibleIndividually = 'True'
        INSERT INTO Mysp_abc_Product(ProductId, abcStatus, IsDeleted, InTime, StoreId, LanguageId) 
            SELECT 
                p.Id, 1, 0, GETDATE(), s.Id, l.Id 
            FROM
                Language l, Store s, Product p 
            LEFT JOIN 
                Mysp_abc_Product isp on isp.ProductId = p.Id 
            WHERE
                isp.Id IS NULL 
                AND p.Deleted = 'False' 
                OR p.Published = 'True' OR VisibleIndividually = 'True'

        --Insert data into Mysp_abc_Product where condition is p.Deleted = 'True' or p.Published = 'False' or  VisibleIndividually = 'False'
        INSERT INTO Mysp_abc_Product(ProductId, abcStatus, IsDeleted, InTime, StoreId, LanguageId) 
            SELECT
                p.Id, 1, 1, GETDATE(), s.Id, l.Id
            FROM
                Language l, Store s, Product p 
            LEFT JOIN
                Mysp_abc_Product isp ON isp.ProductId = p.Id 
            WHERE
                isp.Id IS NULL 
                AND p.Deleted = 'True' 
                 OR p.Published = 'False' 
                 OR VisibleIndividually = 'False'
    END
END
```

Comment: The error message says it all. You have a sub-query that returns more than 1 row where it's not allowed. (Probably that assignment.)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And you should ***most definitely*** not ***MIX*** the two styles!

Comment: I don't see the need for the Dynamic SQL.  Only use dynamic sql if you really have not other choice.

Answer (score 2):

You have problems all over the place.  The error is pretty clear.  It is your code that is not.

For instance, the `delete` call is way overdone.  Why use variables and dynamic SQL at all?  Just run:

```
DELETE FROM Mysp_abc_Product
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT Mysp_abc_Product.Id 
                 FROM Mysp_abc_Product LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Product
                      ON Mysp_abc_Product.ID = Product.ID
                 WHERE Product.ID IS NULL
                );
```

Or, even more to the point:

```
DELETE FROM Mysp_abc_Product abc
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM Product p
                      WHERE abc.ID = p.ID
                     );
```

This is more concise.  It should have better performance.

Note:  This only addresses the first problem in your code.  There are more problems.

My advice is to build the stored procedure by testing each subquery at once.  Don't do the looping in T-SQL.  Use *set-based* operations.

Comment: But if I want to add multiple id then in the place of top(1) what I want to write and then insert data....Here is my query

Comment: set @MyspAddIdFromProduct =   
           (SELECT Product.Id 
            FROM Product 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Mysp_abc_Product ON Mysp_abc_Product.ID = Product.ID
            WHERE Mysp_abc_Product.ID IS NULL)

Comment: @karan . . . I don't understand your comment.  This deletes all matching ids.

Answer (score 1):

```
set @IncrementalRemainingIdFromProduct = 
       (SELECT Incremental_Solr_Product.Id 
        FROM Incremental_Solr_Product 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Product ON Incremental_Solr_Product.ID = Product.ID
        WHERE Product.ID IS NULL)

set @IncrementalAddIdFromProduct = 
       (SELECT Product.Id 
        FROM Product 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Incremental_Solr_Product ON Incremental_Solr_Product.ID = Product.ID
        WHERE Incremental_Solr_Product.ID IS NULL)
```

Your above query returns multiple records for `Incremental_Solr_Product.Id` so need to change it to

```
set @IncrementalRemainingIdFromProduct = 
        (SELECT TOP(1) Incremental_Solr_Product.Id 
         FROM Incremental_Solr_Product 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Product ON Incremental_Solr_Product.ID = Product.ID
         WHERE Product.ID IS NULL)
```

So it will work for you

Comment: Using `TOP(n)` *without* having an explicit `ORDER BY` clause it useless - which "top(1)" are you getting?? You're not defining any *ordering*, so you're basically just getting an **arbitrary row** .....

Comment: But if I want multiple Id then what can I do in the place of top(1)?

Comment: and if I m doing top(n) then it shows error that is "Invalid column name 'n'".

Answer (score 1):

The Error message says it all. In SQL server you can't return more than one value in a subquery.

The problem is with:

```
 set @MyspRemainingIdFromProduct = 
           (SELECT Mysp_abc_Product.Id 
            FROM Mysp_abc_Product 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Product ON Mysp_abc_Product.ID = Product.ID
            WHERE Product.ID IS NULL)
```

The subquery returns more than one Id which is not right.